# Badges for referral links

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges, stack-exchange, referrals

I suggest SO to friends almost on a weekly basis — some of whom have joined, and really enjoy it. Would it be out of the question to consider referral-links, which award the referrer with a "Recruiter" badge after two or three friends have joined, and reached a reputation of 100+?

Perhaps these badges could be named "Recruiter" or "Scout."

Comment: This has already been suggested: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/recruiter-badge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if implemented - most recommendations for a site are going to cause the listener to just type the site name into their browser (either navigate or search). I doubt the referral link would be used in reality.

It also ties into the discussion about [affiliate tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2716/amazon-affiliate-tags) - if readers *here* treat *them* as spam, wouldn't they look at your link as spam?

But please keep recommending the sites ;-p

Answer (score 6):

Indeed, this is now possible:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/

We have Announcer (bronze), Booster (silver), and Publicist (gold).