# Is there a special badge for linking questions within SE?

Tags: discussion, badges, badge-request, hyperlinks

Is there any special badge for linking questions within the SE (including linking questions within the same site like some SO question <-> another SO question)?

EDIT

Links like these are very valuable as they allow to quickly find more information on given subject. I find *linked* answers much more valuable than *related* ones when looking for more information.

Comment: What benefit does that have?  What behavior does it encourage?

Comment: @Rebecca - Does this help with SEO or does it only help if links to SE sites are shared outside the SE network?  Thanks!

Comment: AFAICS there is now: [Announcer (bronze), Booster (silver), and Publicist (gold)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107551/248268).